# How to use valuetype in dnlib in order to insert Console.ReadKey()

Tags: c#, reverse-engineering, dnlib

I am using the dnlib and I want to insert Console.ReadKey() at the end of the Console.WriteLines in another executable.

**The code below partly works. Though the issue is. It produces the MSIL:**

```
IL_0028: call void [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey()
```

**When I want it to produce**

```
IL_015a: call valuetype [mscorlib]System.ConsoleKeyInfo [mscorlib]System.Console::ReadKey()
```

**Code**

```
            ModuleDefMD mod = ModuleDefMD.Load(args[0]);
            ModuleDef mode = new ModuleDefUser(args[0]);
            Importer importer = new Importer(mod);
            AssemblyDef asmr = mod.Assembly;
            foreach (TypeDef type in mod.GetTypes())
            {
                foreach (MethodDef Method in type.Methods)
                {

                    if (Method.Name == "Main")
                    {

                        TypeRef consoleRef = new TypeRefUser(mod, "System", "Console", mod.CorLibTypes.AssemblyRef);
                        MemberRef ReadAll = new MemberRefUser(mod, "ReadKey",
                                    MethodSig.CreateStatic(mod.CorLibTypes.Void),
                                    consoleRef);

                        var method = Method;
                        var instructions = method.Body.Instructions;
                        instructions.Insert(8, new Instruction(OpCodes.Call, ReadAll));
                    }

                }
            }
```

Comment: Seems you have to change `mod.CorLibTypes.Void` to somewhat else.

Comment: @AndreyNasonov I can't locate the other value.